Flutter - webOnlyAssetManager & platformViewRegistry deprecated
I'm currently working on a Flutter app and utilizing the cached_video_player package. Below is the code I'm using for the components:
import 'package:cached_video_player/cached_video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:samsung_site_ui/my_provider.dart';

class MyVideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoPath;
  const MyVideoPlayer({
    Key key,
    required this.videoPath,
  });

  @override
  State<MyVideoPlayer> createState() => _MyVideoPlayerState();
}

class _MyVideoPlayerState extends State<MyVideoPlayer> {
  late CachedVideoPlayerController _cachedVideoPlayerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _cachedVideoPlayerController =
        CachedVideoPlayerController.asset(widget.videoPath)
          ..initialize().then(
            (value) {
              setState(() {});
            },
          );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cachedVideoPlayerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<MyProvider>(
      builder: (context, provider, _) {
        // rest of the code
      },
    );
  }
}

I'm receiving the following message in my debug console when this component is in the widget tree:
The webOnlyAssetManager getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `assetManager` from `dart:ui_web` instead.
The platformViewRegistry getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please import it from `dart:ui_web` instead.

I assumed that this is linked to the package cached_video_player, but if this is not the case, here is the full list of my dependencies so you can tell me which one is deprecated:
dependencies:
  cached_network_image: ^3.4.0
  cached_video_player: ^2.0.4
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  gap: ^3.0.1
  google_fonts: ^6.2.1
  provider: ^6.1.2

The Flutter project is running on the web (Chrome), and everything is working well. However, I would like to avoid using webOnlyAssetManager and platformViewRegistry to get rid of this message. If you have any ideas, I'd appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance for your assistance!
